# NuGet package problems while building DirectX Graphics Samples

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore, directx-12

I've encountered NuGet problems while building [DirectX-Graphics-Samples](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples)

The error occurs with many projects, here is an example:

```
NuGet Package restore failed for project D3D12Multithreading: Unable to find version '1.0.161208001' of package 'WinPixEventRuntime'.   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'WinPixEventRuntime.1.0.161208001' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'. . Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors. 1>------ Build started: Project: D3D12Multithreading, Configuration: Debug x64 ------ 1>D:\Personal\Projects\MyProjects\ProjDirectXGraphicsSamples\Samples\Desktop\D3D12Multithreading\src\D3D12Multithreading.vcxproj(157,5): error : This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is D:\Personal\Projects\MyProjects\ProjDirectXGraphicsSamples\Samples\Desktop\D3D12Multithreading\src\packages\WinPixEventRuntime.1.0.161208001\build\WinPixEventRuntime.targets. 1>Done building project "D3D12Multithreading.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

[Microsoft's suggestions for restoring packages](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105)
[image]

did not help either:

```
NuGet Package restore failed for project D3D12Multithreading: Unable to find version '1.0.161208001' of package 'WinPixEventRuntime'.
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\: Package 'WinPixEventRuntime.1.0.161208001' is not found on source 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\'.
. Please see Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.
NuGet package restore finished.
Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.0389909
========== Finished ==========
```

I am using VS Enterprise 2019(16.5.1), .NET 4.8.03752, SDK 10.0.19041.0.

I have `NuGet package manager` in my VS configuration but not `NuGet targets and build tasks`.

[image]

Here is my `.vsconfig`

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "components": [
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.Runtime.3.1",
    "Microsoft.NetCore.Component.SDK",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TypeScript.3.8",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.JavaScript.TypeScript",
    "Microsoft.Component.MSBuild",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.LocalDB.Runtime",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Common.Azure.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.SQL.CLR",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.5.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IntelliCode",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.IntelliTrace.FrontEnd",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.AppInsights.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.WebDeploy",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.ClassDesigner",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.GraphDocument",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CodeMap",
    "Microsoft.Component.PythonTools",
    "Microsoft.Component.PythonTools.Miniconda",
    "Microsoft.Component.PythonTools.Web",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreIde",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.DiagnosticTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.18362",
    "Component.CPython3.x64",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Python",
    "Microsoft.ComponentGroup.Blend",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.MSIX.Packaging",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.14.Latest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.ArchitectureTools.Native",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Core",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions.CMake",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATL",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForBoostTest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForGoogleTest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ASAN",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Llvm.ClangToolset",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Llvm.Clang",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Llvm.Clang",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop",
    "Microsoft.Component.NetFX.Native",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.NetCoreAndStandard",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Support",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.Universal",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.3.5.DeveloperTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Unity",
    "Component.UnityEngine.x64",
    "Component.UnityEngine.x86",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedGame",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeGame",
    "Component.MDD.Linux",
    "Component.Linux.CMake",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeCrossPlat"
  ]
}
```

What components should be in my VS installation for NuGet to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was to add https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json as the source of `nuget.org` in Visual Studio Tools->Options->NuGet Package manager

Answer (score 0):

The project use package.config file to manage nuget packages.
[image]

So try to modify the `Package Reference` to `Package.config`
[image]